# org agenda view to display today's activities

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I tried to check the daily agenda view with command

`M-x org-agenda-day-view`

Unfortunately, it display the future day instead

[image: Or]

How could solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can write a custom org agenda command that shows the agenda for the current day:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
    '(("t" "Agenda for today" agenda ""
        ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Today's agenda")
         (org-agenda-span 'day)
        ))))
```